# How to set Qt tooltip width

Tags: c++, html, css, qt, tooltip

need to show 2 line text in tooltip with bold and multicolor characters, but seems tooltip has max width and text was cut. I tried to calculate width of text and set width manually, but it doesn't make any effects, seems style = "width: some px" doesn't work for tooltip. Here's the code:

**Edited**

```
QString tooltip = "<div style= \"white-space: nowrap; width: 1500px;\">Some text for tooltip, which is too long</div>";
```

[image: there is no effect on tooltip]

How can I change tooltip width?

Comment: I wouldn't expect having tr's and td's without first having a table tag.  Have you tried keeping it [simple?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795757/is-there-a-better-way-to-wordwrap-text-in-qtooltip-than-just-using-regexp)  i.e. just use br for your second row instead?  Additionally, it seems unnecessary to use QString::fromStdString.

Comment: >it seems unnecessary to use QString::fromStdString
Yes, I edited real code where I used std::string variables before posting this question. :)
And you are right, I can turn off word wrapping without using tr/td, only by <div style= \"white-space: nowrap;\"></div>

Comment: And what about width of tooltip? Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce with behavior. Please provide the code you're using to add a tooltip. Which widget has the tooltip?

Comment: Seems its specific for the project, anyway I found the solution, which partially fix the problem, I set stylesheet for the widget, which should show tooltip: setStyleSheet("QToolTip{ min-width: " + QString::number(width) + "px; width: " + QString::number(width) + "px;}"); but now width is woo long(about 50px), I try to set also max-width, but its has no effect. Thanks.

Comment: This is relevant, you may care to vote: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41051

Answer (score 3):

Using the properties portion of QtCreator/Designer, I used:

```
<html>
<table width="25">
  <tr>
    <td width="25">alwkefjwekf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25">a ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea e</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

This should help clue you in on how to better limit the size of the table.  I  have no doubt that there is probably a more terse way to express this.

A concrete example generated by QtCreator:

```
pushButton->setToolTip(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "    <html>\n"
"    <table width=\"25\"><tr><td width=\"25\">alwkefjwekf</td></tr>\n"
"    <tr><td width=\"25\">a ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea e</td></tr>\n"
"    </table>\n"
"    </html>", 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little bit cleaner ...
Also, don't set "white-space: nowrap;", doing that with a small width will cut off text
And, when possible, don't hard code class names, since there is no __CLASS__ I used __FUNCTION__

If you really want the class name for Qt Linguist ( the translate function ) make sure the RTTI compiler option is on and 
use `typeid(*this).name()`

```
setToolTip( QApplication::translate(__FUNCTION__, "    <html>\n"
                                                  "    <div style=\"width: 300px;\">ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea ea</div>"
                                                  "    </html>", 0
                                 ));
```