# qtooltip show sentence in single line qt

Tags: qt, qt5

showing a tooltip without any rich text in a single line works fine. But i have rich text in my tooltip.

```
QString tooltip="<span class=nobr>This is a much longer line than the first</span>";
```

which is getting displayed in 3 lines. How can i restrict it to 1 line. things i have tried

```
QString tooltip="<nobr>This is a much longer line than the first</nobr>";
QString tooltip="<span class=nobr>This is a much longer line than the first</span>";
QString tooltip="<span 'white-space:nowrap'>This is a much longer line than the first</span>";
```

How can i display a tooltip with rich text in single line
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs state:

[Rich text displayed in a tool tip is implicitly word-wrapped unless specified differently with `<p style='white-space:pre'>`.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtooltip.html#details)

So something like this would work:

```
QString tooltip = "<p style='white-space:pre'>This is a much longer line than the first</p>";
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, the implementation Inspired by your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51154288/2010078